# How to load html5 page properly with out scroll effect in android

Tags: android, html

I want to develop html5 application in android.I am taking WebView and loading url (path to html5 which i place in android assets folder)but iam getting scrolling effect.How should i avoid it, where should i place images and css file

Answer (score 0):

For removing horizontal scroll effect just add it

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```